# How to test Webview is loaded or not without staticTexts in XCTest in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

first time I try to write unit test case. Here am blocking with the following scenario.

When I tap a button, it navigates to a next screen and webview will load. I need to wait for webview loading.

I tried to wait till the staticTexts is visible by below code,

```
let rewards = self.app.staticTexts[“Rewards”]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: “exists == 1”)
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: rewards, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler: nil)
XCTAssert(rewards.exists)
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts[“Rewards Overview”].exists)
```

But In my scenario, when I tap the button it will navigate to next screen and webview will starts to load. But the webview content is always dynamic one. So I need to wait till the webviewDidFinishLoad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `waitForExistence(timeout:)` to return a boolean if an element enters existence within the given timeout - I'd recommend using this for your use case.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing your own function for waiting, since with `waitForExistence(timeout:)`, you can only wait for existence, but it ignores other states of element(`.isHittable`, `.isEnabled` etc) or simply wait for any other boolean.

Plus `waitForExistence(timeout:)` is painfully slow, if you have a lot of tests with a lot of waits (we stopped using it after we wrote our own waiting). It is caused by the system method waiting for additional 1-2s before returning true, if the object exists.

This might help you, however its not Swift, its ObjC: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/running-ui-tests-with-ludicrous-speed/